# What's the difference between 出来/起来?

Tags: grammar, difference, direction-complement

please tell me what is the difference between the 哭出来 / 哭起来 and with other actions (not Direction)

Comment: Can I suggest using 想起来 vs. 想出来 as an example too?  The distinction here is important; it arises often and in my experience is that they're almost never interchangeable.  I have a vague intuitive understanding that the first one is "bring to mind" e.g. a memory and the second is "think up" e.g. a plan, an illusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result particle 出来 indicates "come out / release"

哭**出来** means "**let out** the crying/ **actually** cry" (**not withholding** the action)

~

The result particle 起来 indicates "raise/ begin to"

哭**起来** "**begin to** cry" (situation changes from not crying to crying)

Similarly:

笑出來 = laugh out (actually laugh, not withholding)

笑起來 = begin to laugh

Comment: Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, 出来 means come out or go out:

出来，不然我就砸门了！
Come out, or I'll bust the door down!

Second and also foremost, 起来 means get up, arise, as in 中国国歌

起来！
Arise!
不愿做奴隶的人们！
Those of you who don't want to be slaves

起来 sometimes means up or out:

你是怎么想出来的？
How did you ever think that up?  or How did you ever figure that out?

她猛地坐了起来。
She sat up with a jerk.

But, if you see 出来 with, for example, 想, it doesn't always mean out or up, it may just mean "go out".

谁想出来走走？
Who wants to go out for a walk?

In these sentences below, you can't just use 尝 so the 起来 works some kind of magic, although 尝起来 doesn't mean "start to taste" or "at first taste" or "taste up" or "taste out". This 起来 is untranslatable.

这些叶子尝起来相当苦。
These leaves taste rather bitter.

尝起来味道很好。
It tastes delicious.

Neither do I think 尝 is 尝试 here.
Maybe someone Chinese can explain why we need 起来 in 尝起来 here!

There are apparently 3 possibilities which 起来 can indicate:
1. 用在形容词或动词后， 表示动作或情况开始并继续
2. 用在动词后，表示动作完成或达到目的
3. 用在动词后， 表示印象或看法

Comment: Thank you !!